# Postgresql: extremely slow pagination query when casting timestamptz to date or order by primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

For an example this is my DDL script for tables, some fields have been removed for simplicity.

In short, I have a table of orders and tables with items that appear in this order.

```
create table orders
(
    id         bigserial primary key,
    created_at timestamp with time zone default now() not null
);

create table order_item
(
    id              bigserial primary key,
    order_id        bigint         not null
        constraint order_item_order_id_fkey
            references orders,
    sku_id          bigint         not null,
    item_count      integer        not null,
    item_price      numeric(19, 2) not null,
    item_sum        numeric(19, 2) not null,
    delivery_method jsonb,
    sku_info        jsonb
);
create index orders_item_order_id_ind
    on order_item (order_id);
```

And i have query like this:

```
explain analyse
SELECT o.*,
       sku_ids,
       item_sku_info,
       item_counts,
       item_prices,
       item_sums
FROM (select o.id,
             count(*) over () as total_count,
             o.created_at
      from orders o
      WHERE date(o.created_at) >= '2020-09-01'

        AND date(o.created_at) <= '2020-12-01'
      ORDER BY o.id desc
      limit 1000 offset 1000) o
         INNER JOIN (select oi.order_id,
                            array_agg(oi.sku_id)     as sku_ids,
                            array_agg(oi.sku_info)   as item_sku_info,
                            array_agg(oi.item_count) as item_counts,
                            array_agg(oi.item_price) as item_prices,
                            array_agg(oi.item_sum)   as item_sums
                     from order_item oi
                     group by oi.order_id) oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
ORDER BY o.id desc;
```

I select all orders and aggregate all items by order per row (for correct pagination, without aggregation it is impossible)

Orders are requested page by page, so i use limit offset + count over () to count the total number of items.

Plan for this query:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=2008.93..21305.30 rows=40 width=184) (actual time=129.064..53545.068 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (o.id = oi.order_id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 6286500
  ->  Limit  (cost=2008.64..2008.65 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=10.156..12.794 rows=1000 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=2008.54..2008.64 rows=40 width=24) (actual time=10.036..11.806 rows=2000 loops=1)
              Sort Key: o.id DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 304kB
              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.00..2007.48 rows=40 width=24) (actual time=8.694..9.268 rows=2658 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on orders o  (cost=0.00..2006.98 rows=40 width=16) (actual time=0.021..7.642 rows=2658 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((date(created_at) >= '2020-09-01'::date) AND (date(created_at) <= '2020-12-01'::date))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 5295
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.29..19117.79 rows=7949 width=168) (actual time=0.016..52.987 rows=6288 loops=1000)
        Group Key: oi.order_id
        ->  Index Scan using orders_item_order_id_ind on order_item oi  (cost=0.29..18239.12 rows=46655 width=1435) (actual time=0.008..19.221 rows=35408 loops=1000)
Planning Time: 0.280 ms
Execution Time: 53546.210 ms
```

Extremely slow.
Solutions to speed up query:

1. remove `AND date(o.created_at) <= '2020-12-01'`, but that's not my option
2. replace `AND date(o.created_at) <= '2020-12-01'` to `AND o.created_at <= '2020-12-01'`
3. change sort `o.id desc` to `o.created_at desc`, here i can change the sorting to any other field, except for id.

But why do these solutions speed up the request while the original query is so slow? For example, here is the query plan for solution number 2.

```
Merge Join  (cost=20524.97..21469.14 rows=7949 width=184) (actual time=192.014..195.828 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (o.id = oi.order_id)
  ->  Limit  (cost=812.73..1625.17 rows=1000 width=24) (actual time=14.294..14.530 rows=1000 loops=1)
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.28..2104.51 rows=2590 width=24) (actual time=14.082..14.417 rows=2000 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using orders_pkey on orders o  (cost=0.28..2072.13 rows=2590 width=16) (actual time=0.269..12.684 rows=2644 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((created_at <= '2020-12-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (date(created_at) >= '2020-09-01'::date))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 5310
  ->  Sort  (cost=19712.24..19732.11 rows=7949 width=168) (actual time=174.642..180.456 rows=2181 loops=1)
        Sort Key: oi.order_id DESC
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 66648kB
        ->  Subquery Scan on oi  (cost=0.29..19197.28 rows=7949 width=168) (actual time=0.044..71.873 rows=7954 loops=1)
              ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.29..19117.79 rows=7949 width=168) (actual time=0.042..70.770 rows=7954 loops=1)
                    Group Key: oi_1.order_id
                    ->  Index Scan using orders_item_order_id_ind on order_item oi_1  (cost=0.29..18239.12 rows=46655 width=1435) (actual time=0.015..26.074 rows=46696 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.478 ms
Execution Time: 208.866 ms
```

For 3 solution:

```
Sort  (cost=21227.29..21227.39 rows=40 width=184) (actual time=83.986..88.844 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Sort Key: o.created_at DESC
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 9016kB
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=2008.96..21226.23 rows=40 width=184) (actual time=51.079..66.323 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (o.id = oi.order_id)
        ->  Sort  (cost=2008.67..2008.67 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=5.476..5.728 rows=1000 loops=1)
              Sort Key: o.id
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 103kB
              ->  Limit  (cost=2008.64..2008.65 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=5.204..5.331 rows=1000 loops=1)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=2008.54..2008.64 rows=40 width=24) (actual time=5.116..5.223 rows=2000 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: o.id DESC
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 304kB
                          ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.00..2007.48 rows=40 width=24) (actual time=4.285..4.633 rows=2658 loops=1)
                                ->  Seq Scan on orders o  (cost=0.00..2006.98 rows=40 width=16) (actual time=0.019..3.748 rows=2658 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((date(created_at) >= '2020-09-01'::date) AND (date(created_at) <= '2020-12-01'::date))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 5296
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.29..19117.79 rows=7949 width=168) (actual time=0.041..58.557 rows=6787 loops=1)
              Group Key: oi.order_id
              ->  Index Scan using orders_item_order_id_ind on order_item oi  (cost=0.29..18239.12 rows=46655 width=1435) (actual time=0.018..22.090 rows=38700 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.208 ms
Execution Time: 94.366 ms
```

As I noticed in the original query, there is such a line in the plan

```
  Join Filter: (o.id = oi.order_id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 6286500
```

why is this happening?

Tested on postgresql 12.4, 13.1

Comment: I would start with an index on created_at and not using any cast in your WHERE condition.

Answer (score 1):

A function like `date()` is a black box for the optimizer. It knows quite well how `created_at` is distributed, but without the index it has no clue how `date(created_at)` is distributed.

Since the column is a `timestamp with time zone`, simply remove the `date()` function call.

Comment: I can't create date(created_at) index, cause date is not immutable.
My field created_at - timestamptz.
 I don’t think it’s a matter of the index, because I had sorting by id desc, I replaced it with created_at desc and the query began to execute almost instantly.

Comment: In general, it is not clear to me why all 3 of these points begin to speed up the query, and the initial query is simply unrealistically slow.

Comment: As I said, because of the bad estimate. That makes PostgreSQL choose a nested loop join. If it is a timestamp, simply remove the `date()`.